# How to enforce caching in AFNetworking despite cache headers

Tags: iphone, ios, http, caching, afnetworking

I want to enforce caching in AFNetworking even when cache header is Cache-Control:·private there are no other cache-relevant headers, I understand it will be a time-based cache and I do not have a problem with that.

Please advise even if it's beyond AFNetworking scope.

I am making an iOS 5 iPad app and here are the header files from the XML files I'm trying to cache:

```
HTTP/1.1·200·OK(CR)(LF)
Cache-Control:·private(CR)(LF)
Content-Type:·text/xml;·charset=utf-8(CR)(LF)
Server:·Microsoft-IIS/7.5(CR)(LF)
X-AspNet-Version:·2.0.50727(CR)(LF)
X-Powered-By:·ASP.NET(CR)(LF)
Date:·Wed,·11·Jul·2012·18:42:27·GMT(CR)(LF)
Connection:·close(CR)(LF)
Content-Length:·20464(CR)(LF)
(CR)(LF)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFNetworking uses NSURLConnection, NSURLRequest and It takes advantage of NSURLCache. It doesn't handle cache directly.You could find some more information following this link:[AFNetworking FAQ](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ)

Comment: Hi, my API returns following response

Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2016 07:14:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.30
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 10080
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html


but my app not caching data using AFNetworking, pleaes let me know whats missing in following headers

Answer (score 0):

I found this link that might help you: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/495

Basically, you can override the NSURLConnection.

Comment: I don't think the link mentioned that you should override NSURLConnection. Actually,you just need to set the cache policy of the NSURLRequest.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to override `NSURLConnection`, I'd like to use external cache management, such as [EGOCache](https://github.com/enormego/EGOCache). This will be more flexible that you can change to other cache system anytime.

Answer (score 0):

When you create NSURLRequest (+ requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval: or
– initWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:), you can set cachePolicy of it with the following value.

```
enum {
   NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy = 0,
   NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData = 1,
   NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData =4,
   NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
   NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad = 2,
   NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad = 3,
   NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData = 5
};
typedef NSUInteger NSURLRequestCachePolicy;
```

More detail about cachePolicy can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html).